# Elixir: Extract module from TypedStruct field type

Tags: elixir, metaprogramming

I'm using typed_struct 0.2.1. To reproduce this issue, add the following line to your mix.exs deps:

```
{:typed_struct, "~> 0.2.1"}
```

Add paste this into a file.

```
defmodule MyStruct.Plugin do

  use TypedStruct.Plugin

  @impl TypedStruct.Plugin
  def field(_name, type, _opts) do
    module = fetch_module_from_type(type)
    quote do: @other_struct_collection unquote(module)
  end

  def fetch_module_from_type(type_ast) do
    {_type, module} =
      Macro.prewalk(type_ast, nil, fn
        {:__aliases__, _, _} = collection_module, _ ->
          {collection_module, collection_module}
        ast, acc ->
          {ast, acc}
      end)
    module
  end

end




defmodule MyStruct do

  alias OtherStruct.Collection
  use TypedStruct

  typedstruct do
    plugin MyStruct.Plugin
    field :ships, Collection.t
  end

  IO.inspect @other_struct_collection, label: "I want this to be `OtherStruct.Collection`"

end
```

Now all I'm trying to do is extract the fully qualified module `OtherStruct.Collection` and assign it to `@other_struct_collection`. I can do it by using `Module.fetch_alias`, but I don't to be so explicit about it. I've tried `Module.eval_quoted` and plain old `unquote` as you see here, but I just can't get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly what you want, you just need to use `Collection`. Your problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with `typed_struct`, so I made this simpler example to illustrate:

```
defmodule People.Alice do
end

defmodule People.Bob do
  alias People.Alice

  @friend Alice

  def friend do
    @friend
  end
end

People.Bob.friend() |> IO.inspect() # => outputs People.Alice
```

Comment: to me it seemed that he wanted to get aliases after the use was called, I think using the @after_compile with Module.__info__ should do the job